# Simple editor for Android Permissions File

Tags: android

I am new to Android and Eclipse development, but not new to software development in general.

As my first real project, to get over the learning curve, I am modifying the SDK example soft keyboard.

I would like to add a macro capability. So far so good.

I have created a Permissions file to hold the macro string definitions and store that in the getApplicationInfo().dataDir – which turns out to be something like "/data/data/…". I can write then read back a single key-value pair – so I know the file exists. But, I can't see the file using Astro file manager or an FTP program looking at the Device. I have a feeling I may not have the access permissions to view the directory and I don't have root.

I would have liked to edit the macro definitions in this file on a PC and then save it back to the proper location – that would've been the easy solution. I think my other options are to create a simple key-value parameter by parameter editor or somehow use intents to open the file using some already available text file editor. I am guessing the second option will also encounter the file permissions problem.

A third option would be to store the file in some publicly available directory. I tried using a few "get DIR's", but they required a higher level SDK than I was using – I would like to stay compatible with version 6 and below.

Can somebody offer suggestions on how I can edit the key-value pairs or find a public place to create this file? And, where to look to find an example of how to implement the suggestion?

Thanks much,
Barry.

Comment: if your file is in the dir /data/data... in device's RAM, not sd card, you are not allowed to access it directly. You may root your phone, or you can copy/paste it with DDMS if you are using Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks. But, I would like to maybe give this code to others – so rooting or going through too much effort to modify the file is probably not a good idea. Is there a way to query a directory location on the SD card, with public access, where I can store the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save any data in the SD card. Please read the SDK [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal), where there is a code snippet which may help you.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks to both of you. I hope I can "accept" both answers.

Answer (score 1):

Try saving the file on your SD card.
http://androidgps.blogspot.com/2008/09/writing-to-sd-card-in-android.html